# Trying to create a join of tables when the words end in the same letters of each word of the table in ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
        select a.word,
               b.word
from sec1313_words1 a,
      sec1313_words2 b
where mid(a.word, len(a.word)) = mid(b.word, len(b.word));
```

This is what i was looking for thank you

Comment: How come i could not write it that way to start with? What do i need to do @ jim hewitt

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: Thank you do you think you could help me with my question? @Hiten004

Comment: what happens when you run that query?  In what way does it not work?

Comment: What is your question ? Please add sample table and expected result.

Comment: i just figured it out thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

SELECT A.Id
FROM [Table1] AS A INNER JOIN [table2] AS B ON RIGHT(A.Id,2)=RIGHT(B.Id,2)